# Latitude Longitude tracking in Android Phonegap?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am new to android  platform so I wanted to start my learning with existing sample code. I am trying to acquire GPS Coordinates so i wote the below code. In the below code once the device is started onDeviceReady() method is firing but onSuccess() method is not firing. How to solve this issue? I am using cordova-2.8.0.jar in my project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>  
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;">
        <title>PhoneGap</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    var watchID = null;

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Throw an error if no update is received every 30 seconds
        alert("Test1");
        var options = {
         timeout: 3000
          };
        alert("TEst2"+options);
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
        alert("TEst3");
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
    alert("RAmesh");
       /* var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                            '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;*/
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
      /*  alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');*/
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I rearranged your code a little, try [this](http://pastebin.com/GTjaQ92i). In your watchPosition you are calling onSuccess and onError, but without the parentheses it is looking for variables with those names. If you're going to call it that way then you have to assign a function to those variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your options as follows:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 30000,
  maximumAge: 0
};
```

Ensure you have set permission to use location in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and in your config.xml:

```
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try the instruction of Dpa99c.

Second, use GenyMotion Emulator. It's a awsome emulator for Android : faster than default and you have some widget to modify the location, camera and much more.

Third, I just discover one masive problem in Cordova/PhoneGap :
  - When you open the Android project built by cordova (in commandline), the requestUpdate is set at ..... 60 Seconds !!!!!!!!!!! You have a new Location every Minute ! Evenif you use GPS (enableHighAccuracy="true"). So try to set this at 1000 where you find LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER in org.apache.cordova.geolocation package -> GPSListener class !

Comment: I want to say thank you for your great advice. Yes I have downloaded the GenyMotion Jars, Now how can i include them in eclipse and what can i do to get to use that emulator?

Comment: Just install GenyMotion (with VirtualBix included). Start an Android device : if you have the soft in french, click "Ajouter", choose your device and then click "Lancer". If you have a blackscreen for over 30s, close the window and restart. Then go to your Eclipse (android). Click on the black arrow on the right-side of the green arrow (Run).Then, "Run configuration" -> "target" -> "Launch on all compatible devices/AVD's" and select "Active Device". In fact, GenuMotion acts as a physical Device connected to the computer. If you just click on the green Arrow, you could choose your Geny Device

Comment: Hi, I just want to add GenyMotion plugins to my eclipse. I downloaded the jar and include them in eclipse plugins. then when i am trying to open the genymotion it is showing below error.  "In Genymotion settings, Genymotion directory is not set." When i am opening the genymotion settings i did not get default path to set. how can i set the path.

Comment: you dont have a Geny plugin. You just have to follow the instruction above. I dont understand what you say. Maybe GenyMotion ask for the "ADB Debugger Android" or "SDK". So go to your Android folder, where you have 2 folder : "Eclipse" and "SDK" and 1 file "SDKManger". Select the SDK folder and click OK or Apply and restart your emulator.